# Apache Nifi - About .Nar File Changes and Nifi Restarting

Tags: apache-nifi

I want suggestions for my application:

I have Multitenancy in Nifi. For each Process group, I have different Tenants/Users.

For any changes in one Tenant/user like in his custom processor(.nar file will create), we need to copy-paste that .nar file into lib folder and again restart the nifi. But due to this full Nifi server has restarted because of that Each Tenant/User and Processes group get restarted.

So, Please give Some Suggestions So that we can restart only one Tenant/user or process group Or Without Restart Nifi .nar file will reflect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NiFi does not currently have the kind of warm restart option that you describe, however a lot of the base functionality needed to support it is in the code base and the concept is on the community roadmap.

Some options that might help you today:

1. Consider segregating the tenants with a high rate of code change into separate development environments. You could possibly leverage the Docker builds to provide flexibility and easy automation.  You could then promote the end-of-day versions of your Nars into the 'Production' cluster each night, hopefully without disturbing users.
2. Consider utilising the NiFi Site-to-Site capability to have linked NiFi environments instead of a single shared one. Processors that change regularly could be called out to and updated in their own schedule
3. Consider why you are changing processor code so regularly, there may be a better approach than hard coding logic and parameters into the processors - the variable registry, various controller services, flow registry, etc. all provide a very rich featureset.